# Gridsome context variable not passed to page-query

Tags: graph, vuejs2, gridsome

I can't access a `primaryTag` variable in my GraphQL `page-query`.

What I want to achieve is on a blog Post page:

- display the post content
- display the related posts (based on the first tag)

---

In my `gridsome.server.js`

```js
api.createPages(async ({ graphql, createPage }) => {
    // Use the Pages API here: https://gridsome.org/docs/pages-api
    const { data } = await graphql(`{
      allPost {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            path
            tags {
              id
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }`)

    data.allPost.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
      createPage({
        path: `${node.path}`,
        component: './src/templates/Post.vue',
        context: {
          id: node.id,
          path: node.path,
          primaryTag: (node.tags[0] && node.tags[0].id) || '',
        }
      })
    })
  })
```

then in my `Post.vue`

```js
<page-query>
query Post ($path: String!, $primaryTag: String!) {
  post: post (path: $path) {
    title
    path
    content
  }
  related: allPost(
    filter: { tags: { contains: [$primaryTag] }, path: { ne: $path } }
  ) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        title
        path
      }
    }
  }
}
</page-query>
```

Unfortunately I get the following error: `Variable "$primaryTag" of non-null type "String!" must not be null.

Also, as a side note (and that might be the bug issue) I'm using `@gridsome/source-filesystem` and `@gridsome/transformer-remark` to create my `Post` collection.

---

If you know how to solve this or have a better approach for getting the related posts, comment below.

---

Libs:
- gridsome version: 0.6.3
- @gridsome/cli version: 0.1.1`

Comment: For anyone passing by: https://github.com/gridsome/gridsome/issues/491#issuecomment-500110193